# D3.js: making a circle which is itself made up of rectangles, in SVG

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm quite new to d3/SVG, and I'm trying to make something slightly complex.
Here's an example of the shape I'm trying to draw:
[image: stripey circle]

Any ideas about how I could achieve this? I've been fiddling around with pattern fills without much luck. Or, it's easy to create a rectangle of bars, do I do that and then use it as a fill for the circle? Or, is it a matter of creating six different shapes with the relevant arcs.
Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way may be to simply append rectangles (as you note this is fairly easy) but add a clip path. This will keep things simple for appending rectangles and allow you to change the clip path if you want to change your radius or shape (without having to update each rectangle):

```js
svg = d3.select('body')
   .append('svg')
   .attr('width',500)
   .attr('height',500);
   
color = d3.schemeCategory20;
   
circle = svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx',250)
  .attr('cy',250)
  .attr('r',150)
  .attr('fill','none')
  .attr('id','clipper');
  
clipPath = svg.append('clipPath')
    .attr('id',"clip")
      .append("use")
    .attr("xlink:href","#clipper");
    
rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(d3.range(20))
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x',function(d,i) { return i * 25 })
    .attr('y',0)
    .attr('width',25)
    .attr('height',500)
    .attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color[i]; })
    .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)")
    
animate();
    
function animate() {
  svg.select('circle')
    .transition()
    .attr('r',100)
    .duration(1000)
    .transition()
    .attr('r',200)
    .duration(1000)
    .on('end',animate);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

### Edit:

To add your own colors to the rectangles you could specify your own color array:

```js
var width = 300;
var height = 300;

var svg = d3.select('body')
   .append('svg')
   .attr('width',width)
   .attr('height',height);
   
// Use CSS colors
// var color = ["darkgreen","blue","purple","red","orange","yellow"];

// or Use hex colors:
var color = ["#111","#222","#333","#444","#555","#666"];


var n = 6;


var circle = svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx',width/2)
  .attr('cy',height/2)
  .attr('r',width/2)
  .attr('fill','none')
  .attr('id','clipper');
  
var clipPath = svg.append('clipPath')
    .attr('id',"clip")
      .append("use")
    .attr("xlink:href","#clipper");
    
var rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(d3.range(n))
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x',function(d,i) { return i * width / n })
    .attr('y',0)
    .attr('width',width/n)
    .attr('height',500)
    .attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color[i]; })
    .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The above snippet will append a specified number of rectangles across the circle (`n` in the code), and will append colors to them from the array. In the original example, `d3.schemeCategory20` is just an array. The `i` in the inline function `function (d,i)` will return the element increment which is why an array works easily in getting a fill color.

Comment: Thanks, it looks great! However, how could I add my own list of colours to use, instead of `schemeCategory20` and `range(20)`? When I've tied my own array of colours into the code (calling it seemingly appropriately in the fill attribute), everything goes black.  
Also, I added your code to mine (direct cut and paste, just for checking), but only part of the circle is being filled - just 12 bars are showing. Screenshot: https://s15.postimg.org/awahozp0r/circle_stripes_partial_sml.png  
Any idea why this would be? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: There may be an alignment issue (for example, if you appended the circle to an SVG that was too small). I hard coded my width/height in the original block (I've used variables for width and height in the second). I hope that helps. I've updated the answer to reflect custom color selection.

Comment: thank you again - SO helpful.  I just have one niggling problem - somehow my colour scheme is starting from the **second** element in the array rather than the first. [Screenshot](https://s27.postimg.org/413fzufsj/circle_stripes_almost_there.png). (The lightblue at the left is the background colour I put on the circle). It's clearly something to do with my x-coordinate(s) but it is totally escaping me right now! My code is [here](https://github.com/kfrn/smpte-colourbars/blob/testsrc-test/scripts/main.js), does anything jump out to you? Once again, I'm so grateful for your help.

Comment: My pleasure. I took a gander at your code in the comment above, and it's a tricky thing to spot, but when you make this selection `svg.selectAll('rect')` to append your rectangles, you are selecting the background rectangle that you appended earlier - which means the first item in your data array is associated with this rectangle. You want to ensure your selection is empty when appending new datasets, try for example: `d3.selectAll('.rects').data(d3.range....`. You don't even need to assign the class `rects` in this method, it just ensures an empty selection.

Comment: thank you so much! I have it now. If you are interested, the finished SVG is [here](https://kfrn.github.io/smpte-colourbars/) - third one down. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, nice final product, thanks for the link.